# MPMediaPickerController displaying deleted songs

Tags: ios, objective-c, media, mpmediapickercontroller

I am using the MPMediaPickerController in two separate app, which come from entirely different code bases. When I use this control in my app to select songs, it lists songs that I have deleted from my iPad. The songs are not listed in the iPad music app, but they are displayed in the Music Picker on the 2 apps I am developing.

I have tried deleting my apps, restarting the iPad. This has made no difference.

The problem seems to start after I deleted all the songs off my iPad using the Settings - General - Usage - Music - Edit - Delete option. Which deleted all the songs, so I could then add which ones I wanted. But the ones that were deleted with this process are still listed by the Media Picker.

Any suggestions on what I could try next are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a hunch here, but I'm guessing that if you go into the settings on your phone under the Music section, you'll find that the "Show All Music" toggle is set to off. This will hide clouded music in your library. Then when you present your picker, its `showsCloudItems:` property is set to `YES` by default and therefore shows clouded music.

You could try explicitly setting this property to `NO`.

```
[picker setShowsCloudItems:NO];
```

But I can't promise that will work because I don't know for sure if disabling clouded music in preferences allows the songs to show up in the picker in the first place (Don't have a cable with me to test this).

Comment: I will mark as correct when the system let's me...complaining that I need to wait